# Android C2DM 200 Error

Tags: android, tomcat, websphere, android-c2dm

I'm trying to develop a android app that using push notifications. While using the Tomcat Server I'm able to successfully register and push notification to a device. I get the response back as:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Connection: Keep-Alive, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Content-Type: text/plain, Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, Pragma: no-cache, Expires: Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT, Date: Wed, 11 Apr 2012 17:25:31 GMT, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Server: GSE]
```

But when trying to implement the same code using WebSphere, I encounter the following error for registration:

```
Exception :Exception in executing http post request for Android Registration: HTTP/1.1 200 Error
```

Can anyone point out on what I may be missing between these two different environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by using curl and/or network monitoring/logging to lay out exactly what request is being sent to the C2DM servers.

It certainly seems odd WebSphere is receiving a 200, but showing it as an error. That's where I'd be looking.